# Trying to identify a animated film or series (medieval or fantasy like) I watched once in 1986-1989

Tags: story-identification, movie, medieval

I only remember one scene. In Spanish. It was in colour and looked like the main character and other 2 were in a place like a swamp or a cave. Then a person appeared and ask him to fight them but I remember the line "If you fail you three will lose your head" The good one loses the battle but the other one (that seems evil) respect their lives (I believe one of the heros said something like "please take my life but forgive my colleagues). I also think I remember something like a hydra with several heads but not sure at all.
To me it looked like Kings Arthur men, but I am not sure.

I was always surprised how the main character could lose the battle and how that enemy let them alive.

Edit.
I saw it before 1989 in spain.

It is not:
King arthur and the knights of justice 1992.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USUucZVnno0?

Comment: Thanks, I consider this one, but I remeber that i saw in my old parents house, and we move by 1990,so the film/serie should have been done before 1990 and king arthur and knights of justice was released in 1992. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Did their armor have animal holograms on the chests? If so, could be Visionaries. Or if the knights were kind of insect-looking, could be Sectaurs.

Comment: I believe the wear standard armours or coat of mail. But I will check some cahpters of Visionaries to see if it runs a bell. I dont remember insect looking but the hydra thing could apperar on sectaurs I would also look at that series and come back to confirm. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Mysterious Cities of Gold (1981-1982)? It originally ran outside US 1982-1990 and then saw renewed interest/popularity when it finally started running in US on Nickelodeon 1986-1990? It was weird mix of 16th century world with futurized spaceships, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This may be the Spanish animated series "La corona mágica" (The Magic Crown). It was a 1989 mix of fantasy and space opera with some similarities to the [1979 "Flash Gordon" Filmation animated series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Adventures_of_Flash_Gordon) but with a Gandalf-like wizard mentor figure instead of a Doctor Zarkov.

[image: Credits]

Some of its episodes were long walks through caverns with successive fights with monsters and human enemies and this may be the source of your memories.

[image: Rahman the wizard and his companions]

It is a little known and deservedly forgotten botched series and there are few videos to find a definitive answer but I hope this youtube video helps you with your question.